# OpenCV: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, opencv, segmentation-fault

This is the very basic program:

```
import numpy
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('watch.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I write `python3 opencv.py`, the following error occurs:

```
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x2e43c30) is not the object's thread (0x2ee1060).

Cannot move to target thread (0x2e43c30)

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The error arises due to the line containing `imshow()`. 
Plotting using `matplotlib` works just fine.
Using python2 gives the same error as well.

I have installed/reinstalled opencv using:

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-python

sudo apt install python-opencv
```

Tried installing contrib package while searching for solution

```
sudo pip3 install opencv-contrib-python
```

Tried two different virtual environments namely `conda` and `venv` (clearly it won't have solved the problem)

This is the result of debugging using `gdb python3` > `run opencv.py`

```
Starting program: /home/subtleseeker/virtualenvironment/pp/bin/python3 openCV.py
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff3bac700 (LWP 13322)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff33ab700 (LWP 13323)]
[New Thread 0x7fffeebaa700 (LWP 13324)]
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0xee9360) is not the object's thread (0xf867a0).
Cannot move to target thread (0xee9360)


Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffe24d41ce in xcb_send_request_with_fds64 ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
```

I am using Kubuntu 17.04. I am really out of options, of what else to try. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: related: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9568